# Wrap each span in a container

Tags: javascript

I am trying to wrap each span in a container. To achieve this I used a for loop to create multiple containers and then append the span to the container of the same index.

Why isnt my logic working?

Html: Two span tags (Sorry html code wont show)

Javascript:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
{
      var container = document.createElement('figure');
      container.setAttribute('class', 'container');
      body.appendChild(container);
      container.appendChild(spans[i]);
}
```

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/tsrLutpg/1/

Comment: Where and how is `spans` initialised?

Comment: `createElement()` doesn't create a collection that would need `[i]` – `container.appendChild(...)`.

Comment: Are you reusing the `container` variable? You wrongly redefine it each start of the loop and also use it as an array indexer (wrongly -> see function scope definition javascript, or if es2015 `let` keyword)? Can you make a fiddle showing the non-working functionality or do you get errors in your code (like appendChild not found on undefined)

Comment: @AdamJeffers spans= document.getElementsByTagName('span'),

Comment: @Icepickle I will make a fiddle

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: @Icepickle https://jsfiddle.net/tsrLutpg/1/

Comment: @AdamJeffers edited and supplied jsfiddle

Comment: It'll likely help to create a static collection from the *live* `HTMLCollection`. You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for that – `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('span'));`. https://jsfiddle.net/wt84421u/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski very clean. Can you post an answer explaining the pro and cons of your method compared to the ones below? For example ioseb posted an answer but yours seems to be better performancewise? Im not sure but it seems more right

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I just checked and it is an esmascript 6 technology. Wont be very compatible

Comment: Just wondering why it would not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the reason for the oddity is because the `HTMLCollection` set to `spans` is "*live*." This means, as you modify a `<span>`, the collection changes to reflect that change.

In this case, the collection changes the order the `<span>`s are listed in. As you're iterating, some may be wrapped twice moving from one `<figure>` to another, while others may remain unaltered when they move to an index that's already been visited.

```
<span>Foo</span>
<span>Bar</span>
<span>Baz</span>
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
{
    // ...
    console.log(Array.from(spans).map(s => s.outerHTML));
    container.appendChild(spans[i]);
}
// ["<span>Foo</span>", "<span>Bar</span>", "<span>Baz</span>"] (1 2 3)
// ["<span>Bar</span>", "<span>Baz</span>", "<span>Foo</span>"] (2 3 1)
// ["<span>Bar</span>", "<span>Foo</span>", "<span>Baz</span>"] (2 1 3)
```

---

You can avoid this by creating a static collection of the `<span>`s to iterate over, that doesn't change as the `<span>`s change.

In modern browsers, you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for this (similar to the above snippet).

```
var spans = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('span'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/394La14t/

---

For compatibility, [MDN offers a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) you can use. Or, you can call [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead.

```
var spans = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('span'), 0);
```

Comment: I really like your answer the most. Oh yes, how could I be so stupid and not realize this. Changing the number of spans to iterate over messes up my for loop right?

Comment: @Asperger The count remains consistent. The collection just has a tendency to shuffle the elements as their parentNodes change.

Comment: Such an awesome answer : )

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution that properly wraps span tags:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
   var container = document.createElement("figure");
   container.className = "container";
   var span = spans[i];
   span = span.parentNode.replaceChild(container, span);
   container.appendChild(span);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery library on the page, you could use next line of code:

```
$("span").wrap("<div class = 'outer'></div>")
```

Comment: I prefer using pure vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution using `insertBefore`, before `appendChild`:

```js
var containers = [];
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
      containers[i] = document.createElement('figure');
      body.insertBefore(containers[i],spans[i]);
      containers[i].appendChild(spans[i]);
}
```

```css
span {
background-color: rgb(191,191,255);
}

figure {
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

```html
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>ABC</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just respect the order of your `spans`, instead of inserting the container after all of their spans insert it where the old span used to be. Change:

```
body.appendChild(container);
```

To:

```
spans[i].parentNode.insertBefore(container, spans[i]);
```

And now it works:

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
{
      var container = document.createElement('figure');
      container.setAttribute('class', 'container');
      spans[i].parentNode.insertBefore(container, spans[i]);
      container.appendChild(spans[i]);
}
```

```html
<span></span>
<span></span>
```